# Допустимо ли такое выражение?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

Возник такой вопрос. Допустимо ли, чтобы губы шептали и переходили на звонкий крик?
Мои поиски в корпусе русского языка особо не увенчались успехом. Слишком мало примеров.

– Кэрол...? – прошептали испуганно губы, переходя на звонкий крик. –
Кэ-э-э-ро-о-о-л!

Comment: @IvanOlshansky Доброй ночи, Иван! Правка, мне кажется, получилась не совсем удачная. Буковка "л" с восклицательным знаком отвалились как-то от общего текста. Думаю, надо убрать знак цитирования, оформить курсивом (тогда, наверно, всё "влезет" в одну строку). И метка "фразеология" тут, считаю, не к месту. P. S. Извините, если что-то Вам покажется *злым*.

Comment: прошептали испуганно губы, а горло сорвалось на звонкий крик

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, судя по всему, у меня в браузере этот текст отображается не так, как у Вас. Я примерно догадываюсь, о чем речь, но увидеть это не могу. Если Вас не затруднит, подправьте, пожалуйста, этот текст так, чтобы все было корректно - а я буду стараться впредь не трогать такие широкоформатные цитаты, чтобы вновь не наступать на подобные "грабли".

Answer (score 0):

Если только "губы" - это некая сказочная сущность. А в разговоре с человеком губы прошептать могут, но перейти на крик это уже чьё-то другое действо. Например, Сергея.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ). Я так и думала)